# Floating deck substructure—which is the better approach?

Tags: deck, decking, planning, composite, pier-blocks

I'm planning a 16x19' ground-level floating deck, using deck blocks (they work well in my area). A big box store gave me a rough deck plan and materials which I've laid out (option 1), but I've seen a number of plans online ([e.g.](https://www.lowes.com/n/how-to/planning-a-floating-deck)) where more deck blocks are placed near the rim instead of supporting the center beam (option 2).

All the substructure is pressure treated lumber. Rims are 2x10"s, everything else is 2x8". Joists are 12" oc as I'm using composite boards. The structure at top right is a window well.

Any opinion on which option is better? Any potential issues with either of these plans?

[image: Option 1][image: Option 2]

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to have three deck blocks per joist?

Comment: I would opt for the top drawing myself.  I'm not a deck building expert, but my line of thinking is that I would like to have a greater amount of support in the center rather than the outer rim.  I would put greater weight on something recommended by a local entity than an internet source, given the local being more likely to know the nuances of the area.

Comment: Materials included joists hangers throughout, and through bolts to laminate the edge beams, right? So **a support every 5' or less** [iirc](https://www.chicago.gov/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/EZPERMIT/PorchGuidelinesMay2011.pdf) on the edge beams and the center beam. Also If I were doing it, it'd be 2x12s and 2x10s.

Comment: Wait... it's railing posts less than 5'. With 2x12s... I think you get almost 8' between supports. IDK... read the manual ;)

Comment: If you don't want blocks sticking out, you run another beam under all the joists and it become a cantilever; never seen that many blocks anywhere. When it settles it will do so unevenly, but not if there was another beam. I've however, never used these blocks.

Comment: I'm not against 3 per joist, but these are design options I've been given/seen.

Good point about putting more trust on local building recommendations.

Joist hangers, yes. No bolts. The blocks won't be visible because of the cantilevering and the 2x10" edge rims.